# Condition based filtering for the target field

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Below is my xml input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <DELVRY07>
 <IDOC BEGIN="1">
  <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
     <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
     <MANDT>100</MANDT>
  </EDI_DC40>
  <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
     <VBELN>0080000646</VBELN>
     <VSTEL>1710</VSTEL>
      <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTNER_Q>AG</PARTNER_Q>
        <PARTNER_ID>0017100001</PARTNER_ID>
        <JURISDIC>GA00000000</JURISDIC>
        <LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>
        <FORMOFADDR>Company</FORMOFADDR>
        <NAME1>Domestic US Customer 1</NAME1>
     </E1ADRM1>
     <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTNER_Q>SP</PARTNER_Q>
        <PARTNER_ID>PL1047</PARTNER_ID>
        <LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>
        <NAME1>W. L. GORE &amp; ASSOCIATES, INC</NAME1>
        </E1ADRM1>
     <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTNER_Q>WE</PARTNER_Q>
        <PARTNER_ID>0017100001</PARTNER_ID>
        <JURISDIC>GA00000000</JURISDIC>
        <LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>
        <FORMOFADDR>Company</FORMOFADDR>
        <NAME1>Domestic US Customer 1</NAME1>
       </E1ADRM1>
     <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTNER_Q>OSP</PARTNER_Q>
        <PARTNER_ID>1710</PARTNER_ID>
        <JURISDIC>7700000000</JURISDIC>
        <LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>
        <NAME1>Shipping Point 1710 - Address Name 1</NAME1>
       </E1ADRM1>
      <E1ADRM1 SEGMENT="1">
        <PARTNER_Q>OSO</PARTNER_Q>
        <PARTNER_ID>1710</PARTNER_ID>
        <JURISDIC>7700000000</JURISDIC>
        <LANGUAGE>EN</LANGUAGE>
        <NAME1>Sales Organization 1710 - Address Name 1</NAME1>
        </E1ADRM1>
     </E1EDL20></IDOC></DELVRY07>
```

in the above xml I need to filter out the condtion for PARTNER_Q. if PARTNER_Q =WE then pass the value of related NAME1 field value to the target.

I have tried below XSL code but not able get the correct logic for filtering

```
<xsl:variable name="vPartnerfunction" select="$nodes_in/PARTNER_Q"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vName" select="$nodes_in/NAME1"/>
   <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$vPartnerfunction = 'WE'">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vName"/>
  </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
```

Please help me out on this.

In the output only i should get the below value

```
   <NAME1>Domestic US Customer 1</NAME1>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The result you show can be produced quite easily by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DELVRY07">
    <xsl:copy-of select="IDOC/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='WE']/NAME1"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, if there are more than one `E1ADRM1` element that meets the condition, the result will be an XML fragment - not a well-formed XML document.

Comment: I think my application not supporting with 1.0 version. I have changed the code with supported syntax but it's giving empty value in the output.    <xsl:value-of select="$nodes_in/E1EDL20/E1ADRM1[PARTNER_Q='WE']/NAME1"/>

Comment: @janardhand I am afraid I don't know how to help you. If your application does not support XSLT 1.0, then your question is not about XSLT.

Comment: I am getting the below error message while executing **An xsl:function element must not contain an xsl:template element, Element xsl:template must be top-level (a child of xsl:stylesheet, xsl:transform, or xsl:package)**

Comment: @janardhand You can see my code working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiorv2z. There is no `xsl:function` element in my code. BTW,  `xsl:function` requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.